# Convert history of dates into date ranges in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date-range

In my application I have a mysql table where I have maintained the history of price alteration. I mapped the dates out of the history table and it looks like this:

`['09-16-2019','09-25-2019','10-10-2019',...n]`

Using this history, I want to create an array of date ranges so that I can easily figure out which client in my application registered between what date range. The format I want looks like :

```
let ranges = [ 
        {start:'09-16-2019',end:'09-24-2019'},
        {start:'09-25-2019',end:'10-09-2019'}
        .,
        .,
        ..n
      ]
```

Comment: Need more explanation.

Comment: how do you determine the start date and end date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `Array.prototype.reduce()` to create an object from the given `dates` array, like so:

```js
let dates = ['09-16-2019', '09-25-2019', '10-10-2019', '18-10-2019'];

let ranges = dates.reduce((acc, val, i, arr) => {
  if (i !== 0) acc.push({
    start: arr[i - 1],
    end: val
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(ranges);
```

Comment: Chalaris, "reduce": That did the trick. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: @Shan remember to upvote and/or accept answers you found useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your example, what you have is list of start dates, you can iterate and figure out end date.

```
let x = ['09-16-2019','09-25-2019','10-10-2019']
let res = [];
for(let i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
    let start = x[i];
    let end = new Date(Date.parse(x[i+1]) - 86400000).toLocaleDateString("en",{year:"numeric",month:"numeric",day:"numeric"});
    res.push({start, end})
}

console.log(res); 
// [ { start: '09-16-2019', end: '9/24/2019' },  
// { start: '09-25-2019', end: '10/9/2019' } ]
```